# itext java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DefaultAccessibilityProperties

Tags: itext, itext7

I don't understand why I get an exception in this very basic test of iText :

```
package com.itextpdf.testpdf4;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.List;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@WrapToTest
public class HelloWorld {


    public static final String DEST = "result/hello.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {

        LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("C:\\dev\\testPDF4\\src\\main\\java\\com\\itextpdf\\testpdf4\\itextkey1544447451310_0.xml");

        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new HelloWorld().createPdf(DEST);

    }




    public void createPdf(String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

 // Create a PdfFont
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
        // Add a Paragraph
        document.add(new Paragraph("iText is:").setFont(font));
        // Create a List
        List list = new List()
            .setSymbolIndent(12)
            .setListSymbol("\u2022")
            .setFont(font);
        // Add ListItem objects
        list.add(new ListItem("Never gonna give you up"))
            .add(new ListItem("Never gonna let you down"))
            .add(new ListItem("Never gonna run around and desert you"))
            .add(new ListItem("Never gonna make you cry"))
            .add(new ListItem("Never gonna say goodbye"))
            .add(new ListItem("Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you"));
        // Add the list
        document.add(list);

        //Close document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/tagutils/DefaultAccessibilityProperties   at
>   com.itextpdf.testpdf4.HelloWorld.createPdf(HelloWorld.java:56)

(line 56 is : document.add(new Paragraph("iText is:").setFont(font)); )

This code comes from here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/fr/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-1 -> C01E02_RickAstley.java

In the POM.XML :

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>testPDF4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
```

(package is : package com.itextpdf.testpdf4;)

Here is the complete POM.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>testPDF4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>


    <properties>
        <itext.version>7.1.4</itext.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>itext</id>
            <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-sandbox-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


       <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.p12</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>com.itextpdf.xml</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- see goals wiki page for configuration options -->
                    <flowInitContext>
                        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
                        <developBranchName>develop</developBranchName>
                        <featureBranchPrefix>feature/</featureBranchPrefix>
                        <releaseBranchPrefix>release/</releaseBranchPrefix>
                        <hotfixBranchPrefix>hotfix/</hotfixBranchPrefix>
                        <versionTagPrefix />
                    </flowInitContext>
                    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <updateDependencies>true</updateDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>public</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com/itextpdf/xml/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*.p12</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>internal</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.p12</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <classifier>INTERNAL</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Does anyone see something wrong ? I don't

Thanks

Comment: Compilation is OK ; But execution failed 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/tagutils/DefaultAccessibilityProperties
 at com.itextpdf.testpdf4.HelloWorld.createPdf(HelloWorld.java:56)
 at com.itextpdf.testpdf4.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagutils.DefaultAccessibilityProperties
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

Comment: You're mixing different itext artifact versions, 7.0.4 and 7.1.4:

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing different core itext artifact versions, 7.0.4 and 7.1.4.

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Don't mix these. Use the same version of all your core itext artifacts.

By the way, you put your test project into the itext group:

```
<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
<artifactId>testPDF4</artifactId>
```

You shouldn't do that, in particular not with production use projects.

Comment: Thanks ^^
I add also a 'nbactions.xml' with theses bad values

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left, right beneath the voting arrows and the vote count).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot mkl ; 
Bad group IP, Bad versions, and a wrong nbaction.xml